# C++ Windows 8 no result after compile

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I have Windows 8 64bit. I try to run a simple program written in C++. I used DevC++ and CodeBlocks but I have the same problem only in Windows 8. I tried on Windows XP and it was perfectly running.

Result after compile and run.(tested on DevC++ too):

[image: Result after compile and run...(tested on DevC++ too)]

Comment: Please add the error message in the content of your question instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Avast? Is so try disabling and then test if program runs.

If it fixes problem add exception for your folder with c++ projects. Or try different antivirus.